# WCF Service Library Connection Issue to DAL in an ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, wcf, dll

I have the following set up in the same solution.

- A WCF Services Library with one main service called MatchService.cs
- A DAL with a EntityDataModel for my classes which retrieves my information about football matches from a DB
- An ASP.NET Website which is hosting the WCF Service Library Match Service (from the WCF service libracy mentioned above)

My problem is that this fine runs locally, but not on the production server. Locally the WCF project has an app.config from which it gets the connection details for the DB DAL, however I'm thinking that this does not get put into the compiled .dll for the WCF Services Project as I get the following error when I upload this to the production site:

"The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state."

So I thought it would attempt to get the DB details from the web.config, however this does not seem to be the case either.

Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

I have now removed all attempts to access the DAL and Im still not able to access the service via the WCF test client when the service is on the hosted environment. The WCF test client is on my local machine. I can get the methods to appear in the WCF Test client however when I try to invoke one of them I get the following error:

```
The caller was not authenticated by the service.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.CommunicationObjectSecurityTokenProvider.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.ClientSecurityChannel`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri via, SecurityToken currentToken, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IMatchService.GetMatches()
   at MatchServiceClient.GetMatches()

Inner Exception:
The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.ThrowIfNegotiationFault(Message message, EndpointAddress target)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody(Message incomingMessage, SspiNegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState)
```

Comment: Are you able to navigate to your WCF service via a browser?  Take the end-point address and see if it'll come up in the browser.

Comment: Yes I can navigate to the service in the browser, however I cant access the methods in the browser? I cant put the address on here but I can relay any info required.

Comment: Your servicemodel config bits need to be in the web.config of your hosting project.  Are they?

Comment: Yes they are in place. When I remove all attempted DB access from the service and manually add some items in by code and then upload the service, then I have no problems at all. Its when it is attempting to use the DAL to retrieve DB items via the WCF Services library.

Comment: In a case like this I'd be tempted to put a debug release on a staging server (or a second set of URLs on the production server) and hook up with the [Remote Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx).  Could you try this?

Comment: Does the production server have the correct version of .Net installed, including the assemblies need for your DB?

Comment: Are your DB connection strings in your web.config file for your hosting project/

Comment: Ill add in an edit above as I have discovered a little more now and I dont think its specific to the DAL now after all, sorry about that, i thought it was.

Answer (score -1):

check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx), it looks like your issue.

Comment: Thanks for this but I already got rid of all my using statements and it didnt help?

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) for you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the link for reference. Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.